# Wireless Internet not working - cannot activate broadcom proprietary driver

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom

I have seen this question asked by others but despite trying as many solutions as I can nothing seems to be working!

The closest I have come is using the answer to this question

[Broadcom driver woes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252958/broadcom-driver-woes)

which says i have connected to the wireless network, but it doesn't actually work.

I have an additional driver (the Broadcom STA wireless driver and from my play with the terminal its BCM 4312) but it will not activate.

What else can I try? And what other info would be helpful for you?

I am loving everything else about Linux and excited to use it on the wireless! Thanks for any help.

---Update---

The below path worked brilliantly - thank you so much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285463/bcm-4312-lp-phy-card-doesnt-detect-any-wireless-networks

Answer (score 2):

Please do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
sudo modprobe -r wl
sudo modprobe b43
```

now your wireless should be working.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please post the output of 
    lspci -nn -d 14e4:

There is a bug in the `wl` module.  Try downloading [this](https://launchpad.net/~eugenesan/+archive/ppa/+sourcepub/3331324/+listing-archive-extra) patched package to see if that fixes the problem.

Here's a link to information on the `b43` driver.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

Comment: The result is...

0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)

Comment: Ok I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

JFYI, I'm using a Dell Latitude D620 with a broadcomm wireless driver. I'm testing out ubuntu 14.04 LTS for my first time today (I've tried other versions and still prefer backtrack 5 / ubuntu 10.04)

My wireless card was not activating by default, but I found this page and followed these instructions:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source

sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-lpphy-installer

sudo modprobe -r wl

sudo modprobe b43
```

the third line was bugged, "wl" was not found. So I followed this link as described above:

https://launchpad.net/~eugenesan/+archive/ppa/+sourcepub/3331324/+listing-archive-extra (I chose the amd64 version) which launches ubuntu software center by default...

One trend I've noticed with Ubuntu Software Center is that often it installs 90% of a package and never "finishes" installing the package - and this is what happened again. Regardless, what has worked in the past is to close Ubuntu Software Center (which I did). The package was installed as far as I could tell, but in terminal, I tried "sudo modprobe -r wl" and got the response "wl is busy" so I restarted my pc. Lo and behold, after restart and third attempt at this line "sudo modprobe -r wl" my wifi indicator immediately lit up and it seems to be working fine. Thank you kindly for your help. I just wanted to let fellow linux users know that this worked for me, and also how I had to get it to work. Cheers!

PS I am running on 2gb of ddr2 ram, with a dual-core processor @ approx 1.85ghz... Which means I still prefer backtrack 5  / ubuntu 10.04 for my daily computing needs/desires. I feel ubuntu 12 and 14 (I did not try 13) are too bloated, and while there are some nice ideas I see coming to life, they do not to my knowledge follow the KISS method. Thanks anyways :) I will still give ubuntu 14 a shot on this machine. Much love ~

***EDIT***

I might keep ubuntu 14, due to the fact that I am unable to get flash player working in either chromium or firefox with backtrack 5 / ubuntu 10.04; if anyone out there has found a workaround, please send me a link @ beautiful.insanity.420@gmail.com... Thank you!