# How to install broadcom LP-PHY drivers?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, dell, broadcom

My Dell Inspirion is equipped with a Broadcom 14e4 4315 Low-Power wifi card. I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my system with hopes of making it my number one OS.

When I booted it up, my wifi card didn't show up. I tried installing the additional drivers that come with the driver via: `Settings` > `Additional Drivers`. But before it installs, it always says it fails and gives me a log file reference.

I have already tried unblocking the `rfkill` list and it is neither hard or soft blocked. I also tried another tutorial from the ubuntu site on how to install the drivers and installed the `broadcom-sta-source` and `broadcom-sta-common` packages, and this didn't help.

I really need to have my wireless card working for this to be a productive machine.

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285463/bcm-4312-lp-phy-card-doesnt-detect-any-wireless-networks

Answer (score 0):

I answered this question for someone else [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345623/wireless-internet-not-working-cannot-activate-broadcom-proprietary-driver/345631#345631).

Absurdly, one of the moderators gave my answer a -1, even though the questioner thanked me because my answer solved his problem.

Anyway, I suggest giving it a try to see if it helps.  FYI, the wireless card in the previous question was a Broadcom 4312 LP-PHY, but I think the patch will work either way.  Good luck!

And - moderators - go ahead and mark down my answer again.  Zero reputation is just another word for having nothing left to lose.