# No wifi on HP Pavilion DV7 with Ubuntu 12,04

Tags: 12.04, networking, wireless, drivers, broadcom

I recently updated to 14.04 but I found a whole lot of problems and decided to revert my changes with a clean install of 12.04. I didn't have any problems with the wifi before but now I can't seem to get it online

running `nmcli nm`

```
RUNNING   STATE        WIFI-HARDWARE WIFI     WWAN-HARDWARE  WWAN
running   disconnected enabled       enabled  enabled        disabled
```

running `vi /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state`

```
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
```

running `iwconfig`

```
eth0  no wireless extensions
lo    no wireless extensions
```

running `ifconfig` only gives `eth0` and `lo` so no `wlan` interface

running `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

```
07:00,0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:165a]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
--
0d:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4727] (rev 10)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:145a]
Kernel modules: bcma
```

running `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source 
[sudo] password for timothy: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
bcmwl-kernel-source is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 1):

The driver will be installed by

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Comment: Didn't work, is already the latest version..

Comment: According to your output in the question, it is not installed. `Kernel modules: bcma`.

Comment: And according to the output I received from the apt-get install it is, see updated question

Comment: In 12.04 it may be not supported. Try `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`.

Comment: It aborts with following error: Unsupported device(s) found: PCI id 14e4:4727 The wifi has worked before btw with 12.04

Answer (score 0):

Following answer did the trick:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

If it isn't installed, just proceed.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo modprobe -r b43 && sudo modprobe b43
```

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252958/broadcom-driver-woes)